# Upgrading Android MarketingCloudSDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, upgrade

For our Android app, we are upgrading the MarketingCloudSDK from 5.5.0 to 7.3.1 and am slightly confused by what needs to be done as I was not involved in the original implementation.

Going through the latest integration instructions [here](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/), my understanding is that Marketing Cloud will essentially send push notifications via Firebase, but how much integration is needed between Firebase and the Android app?

For example, in order to use the MarketingCloudSDK, is it necessary to integrate with Firebase as per the instructions on their website? For example, is installing google-services.json necessary (something we don't have for our Android app right now)?

Is it necessary to implement Firebase classes like [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) or will the MarketingCloudSDK handle all the required logic for messages so extending FirebaseMessagingService is pointless?

Marketing Cloud is the only push notification provider we're using.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 1 push provider within your application then you simply need to create your firebase project, add FCM and get your key(s), add the google-services.json to your app, and init the SDK.

See https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/provisioning/google.html

Comment: Thanks for your response, Bill. One thing I don't quite understand is how when using the old 5.5.0 SDK, we don't need google-services.json in the app but push notification works fine magically? Was there a different format for this file in the past?

Comment: Google added the requirement.